# How to show content on the product view depending on category ID?

Tags: php, magento

I have this code snippet which works for displaying content depending on which top category the product belongs to:

```
<?php $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds(); if($categoryIds[0]!= '42'):?>
   CONTENT HERE...
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is put in the list.phtml and view.phtml under catalog/product in Magento 1.6.1 Community Edition. This code works for one ID but when I try adding:

```
<?php $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds(); if($categoryIds[0]!= '42' || $categoryIds[1]!= '43'):?>
   CONTENT HERE...
<?php endif; ?>
```

it doesn't work anymore. Can some of you Magento Wizards help a  poor soul out?!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try changing the `||` to `&&`? Otherwise, you'll have to specify what you mean by it not working any more....

Comment: By not working I mean that nothing happens. The content is still showing even if I'm in category "42" or "43". I will try right away! Thanks!

Comment: Tried it out! Still shows the stuff for category "43" :)

Comment: Oh, wait - you're accessing two separate entries in `$categoryIds` - is that right? You're comparing `$categoryIds[0]` to 42, and `$categoryIds[1]` to 43. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous post from **Guerra** is almost correct. He only messed up a little with logic - you need logical AND instead of OR there:

```
if(!in_array('42',$categoryIds) && !in_array('43',$categoryIds))
```

otherwise the case will return true both for 42 and 43 categories (because of OR).

Comment: Awesome! I tried OR instead, of course wrong! :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try change your if statment by

```
if(!in_array('42',$categoryIds) || !in_array('43',$categoryIds))
```

its better than compare to fix position. Cuz if your function return 43 and 42 in order you can't get right on position 0 and 1.

Comment: Tried this before. Didn't work for me. The HTML is still populated in the DOM when in cat 42 and 43.